# HINSTANCE & HWND Corrupted when passed around functions

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a funny error occurring at runtime where my `HINSTANCE` and `HWND` variables are getting corrupted. I have posted the debugging output below and the line of code where the runtime error occurs. *Note: even though the screen capture kindof shows the HWND isn't corrupted, it doesn't point to the right/valid window anymore

Why is this problem occurring and how can I fix it?

> WindowTiler.exe!WindowLayoutComponent::init(const IEventArgs & evtArgs) Line 26 C++
>     [External Code]
>     WindowTiler.exe!EventDelegate::operator()(const IEventArgs & evtArgs) Line 21   C++
>     WindowTiler.exe!IApp::eventHandler(const int & evtId, const IEventArgs & evtArgs) Line 20   C++
>     WindowTiler.exe!Win32App::wndProc(HWND__ * hwnd, unsigned int message, unsigned int wParam, long lParam) Line 18    C++
>     [External Code]
>     [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for user32.dll]
>     WindowTiler.exe!Win32App::initInstance(const Win32AppInit & evtArgs) Line 154   C++
>     WindowTiler.exe!Win32App::init(const IEventArgs & evtArgs) Line 100 C++
>     WindowTiler.exe!App::init(const IEventArgs & evtArgs) Line 45   C++
>     WindowTiler.exe!WinMain(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance, HINSTANCE__ * hPrevInstance, char * lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) Line 16   C++
>     [External Code]

```
Status WindowLayoutComponent::init(const IEventArgs& evtArgs)
{
    auto args = (const WinEventArgs&)evtArgs;

    HWND btn = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, _T("Button"), _T("Test"), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT,
        30, 30, 50, 50, args.hwnd, NULL, args.hinstance, 0); // LINE 26

    return S_SUCCESS;
}
```

[image]

**Edit:** There are 2 `IEventArgs` objects involved. One passed to `App::init(const IEventArgs & evtArgs)` and another different object created in `Win32App::wndProc` and passed to `IApp::eventHandler(const int & evtId, const IEventArgs & evtArgs)`.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK Win32App::wndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    WinEventArgs args { hinstance, hwnd, wParam, lParam };
    eventHandler(message, args);
    ...
```

Comment: The `args` variable is dead once the call to `CreateWindowEx` occurs, so the values in the debugger ate not meaningful.

Comment: @RaymondChen, the Raymond Chen! :D, thanks for your comment. Can you elaborate. I dont quite understand how, why the variable is dead at that point?

Comment: `auto args = ...` creates a copy on the stack.

Comment: A variable is dead at the point were its no longer used. After being evaluated as arguments to `CreateWindowEx` the variable `args` is not used again anywhere else in the function so it's dead at that point. Since it's no longer being used the compiler could use its storage on the stack (or in registers) for something else. That should only happen with optimization turned on, so it shouldn't happen in debug builds. So the fact that you're seeing garbage values doesn't mean much. Without a complete example its impossible to say what your actual problem is.

Answer (score 0):

After extensive debugging I have found the problem and solved it. I'm surprised the compiler didn't catch this error. It's actually quite interesting what went wrong. The problem was here...

```
struct IEventArgs
{

};

struct WinEventArgs : public IEventArgs
{
    WinEventArgs() = delete; 
    WinEventArgs(const HINSTANCE& hinstance, const HWND& hwnd, const WPARAM& wParam, const LPARAM& lParam) :
        hinstance(hinstance), hwnd(hwnd), wParam(wParam), lParam(lParam)
    {}

    const HINSTANCE& hinstance;
    const HWND& hwnd;
    const WPARAM& wParam;
    const LPARAM& lParam;
};

class EventDelegate
{
public:
        // the problem is here: the parameter should be 'const IEventArgs&'
    typedef std::function<Status(IEventArgs)> EDelegate;

    EventDelegate(EDelegate delegate, GUID gUidContext);

    Status operator()(const IEventArgs& evtArgs)
    {
        return delegate(evtArgs);
    }

private:
    GUID gUidContext;
    EDelegate delegate;
};
```

I've produced a simple example of the problem that people can reproduce. Whilst I've fixed it, what exactly was going wrong, was it that a copy was being made and I hadn't implemented a copy constructor?

```
struct IEventArgs {  };

struct WinEventArgs : public IEventArgs
{
    WinEventArgs(const int& a, const int& b) : a(a), b(b) { }
    const int& a;
    const int& b;
};

class Component
{
public:
    void test(const IEventArgs& evtArgs)
    {
        const WinEventArgs& args = static_cast<const WinEventArgs&>(evtArgs);
        printf("a=1 is: %d, b=2 is: %d\n", args.a, args.b);
    }
};

int main()
{
    WinEventArgs args(1,2);
    Component cmp;

    // Note Component::test's parameter is 'const IEventArgs&' and that the std::function parameter is just 'IEventArgs'
    std::function<void(IEventArgs)> func = std::bind(&Component::test, cmp, std::placeholders::_1);
    func(args);

    // When std::function parameter is 'const IEventArgs&' the cast inside Component::test succeeds
    std::function<void(const IEventArgs&)> func2 = std::bind(&Component::test, cmp, std::placeholders::_1);
    func2(args);

    return 0;
}
```